# symfony 5 how to mock/replace service in container

Tags: symfony

I want to make a mock for some class in my functional test. Let's say I want to mock some custom command bus realization.

First of all I need to register that service as a public in the `services_test.yaml`:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    public: true

  App\CommandBus: ~
```

but still even if I did so I'm getting error `service is already initialized, you cannot replace it` when doing something like:

```
$commandBus = $this->createMock(CommandBus::class);
$commandBus->expects(self::once())
    ->method('dispatch')
    ->with($data)
    ->willReturn($response);
 self::$container->set(CommandBus::class, $commandBus);
```

So how can I easily mock some object and insert mocked version to the container???

Probably I can make some wrapper for tests link it with interface in `services_test.yaml`, and add a methods like `setExpectiotion` which will chekc if expectation set and if so instead of running command return it. But it's extra work and it's taking a lot of time to design such a class for each service I want to mock.

Is there any other way to mock some service?? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Did you try to create a "DummyCommandBus" class that extends CommandBus class and register it in services_test.yaml? As reference check here https://github.com/EnMarche/en-marche.fr/blob/master/config/services_test.yaml

Comment: nope, I told in the description that it probably can be done like that , but it's kind of adding some complexity which I think is unneeded here?  But you are not the first who told me that it's a only way, so thank you! Maybe it looks weird for me after laravel where you can mock and replace container services

Answer (score 0):

I assume your command bus is using an asynchronous transport type. If you wish you can solve this problem using `sync` transport for tests instead. You don't need to mock it in this case, because if you will mock command bus, you will test mock instead of the whole process.

Let's create a new config in `config/packages/test/messenger.yaml`

```yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            command_bus: 'sync://'
```

Then enable the functional test without worrying about the consumer.

---

If you want to debug container for tests, you can check it using command
`./bin/console debug:container -e test`

Please let me know if that solves your problem.